# anchor zero based index in JS

Tags: javascript

Using only JS My Q- n alert should display anchor's zero-based index within a document instead of following the link.

For example, in the document below, the alert should display "2" when Google anchor is clicked since it is the third anchor element in the document and its zero-based index is 2.

```
<body>
  In my life, I used the following web search engines:<br/>
  <a href="//www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a><br/>
  <a href="//www.altavista.com">AltaVista</a><br/>
  <a href="//www.google.com">Google</a><br/>
</body>
```

So far I've got

```
  function registerHandlers() {
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    as[i].onclick = function() {
      alert(i);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

but this is still loading the URL, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: so after a user clicks on google it will not bring them to google.com and alert 2?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Your script to register  clicked anchor is inside function registerHandlers. And this function is not called from anywhere.  Just move the script out of this function and it will work.